# Is SQL Server 2000 Keyboard Scheme available in SSMS 18?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

In Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS), at least up through version 2008 R2, we've had the ability to set the keyboard scheme to "SQL Server 2000" (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard)

[Screenshot of SSMS 2008 R2 Tool Options Keyboard scheme dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmqLa.png)

I'm working with SSMS 18, and, well, that option doesn't appear to be readily available.

Is it still available? If so, can you point me to where I can select it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until I hear otherwise, I'm positing this as an alternative to having the SQL Server 2000 keyboard scheme available.

I'm specifically interested in getting my "comment out" "uncomment" shortcuts of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> back.

I realize that I can alter the existing shortcuts to my liking, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> is already taken by `Edit.MakeUpperCase`, which means that I have to change that shortcut as well.

[Screenshot of SSMS 18 Tool Options Keyboard Scheme dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CUru.png)

As a simple answer, I could simply swap the `Edit.UncommentSelection` and `Edit.MakeUpperCase` shortcuts.